# C# lambda otherwise statement

Tags: c#, lambda

I was wondering if it would be possible to do an other wise type statement within lambda, something similar to:

Have two table structures that looks exactly the same, except for one column, called Synopsis (table 1) and Description (table 2). My component reads either one of the two tables, based on a property, and would like to do a single lambda expression to determine whether the column exists:

```
(from p in table[this.TableName]
 where (p["Description"] != null)
 'otherwise' where (p["Synopsis"] != null)
 select p).First();
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing that accessing a non-existent column doesn't thrown an exception, you should be able to use the logical OR operator (`||`):

```
(from p in table[this.TableName]
 where (p["Description"] != null || p["Synopsis"] != null)
 select p).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot extend the LINQ query comprehension syntax to add new keywords. What you *can* do is add more extension methods, and write your own logic that way - but it won't really help in this case, because a `.Where(...).Otherwise(...)` wouldn't actually **get** any "otherwise" data - the sequence would already have been filtered by the `Where(...)`.

Also: unless that is LINQ-to-Objects, you should probably expect the query interpreter to choke on it. The simpler answer is "no, you can't really do that".

As others have noted, you *can* just simplify the condition via `||`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the logical OR ("||") is the solution, assuming that your indexers return `null` for non-existing columns.